# Agrupar resultados de una Dirección en Mysql, PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, php5

Necesito mostrar todos los departamentos de una dirección como en la siguiente imagen (Ejemplo):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
public function busquedaFilD($datos) { 
    try {

        //De la clase heredada "Conexion" se obtiene la funcion Conectar_BD
        $this->Conectar_BD();
        //Se asigna la cadena de texto de la consulta de MySQL
        $this->query = 'select clave_dir as Clave, direcciones.nombre, tickets.id_depto as Clave, departamentos.nombre_depto, sum(tickets.total) as Total, date_format(tickets.fecha, "%d-%m-%Y") as Fecha  from tickets INNER JOIN departamentos ON departamentos.id_depto=tickets.id_depto JOIN direcciones ON direcciones.clave=tickets.clave_dir';
         if(sizeof($datos->Val)>1){

            if($datos->DatosConsulta[0] != ""){
            switch ($datos->TipoDato[0]) {
                case 's':
                    $this->query.=" WHERE ".$datos->CampoConsulta[0]." LIKE CONCAT('".$datos->DatosConsulta[0]."' , '%')";
                    break;

                case 'i':
                    $this->query.=" WHERE ".$datos->CampoConsulta[0]." LIKE CONCAT(".$datos->DatosConsulta[0]." , '%')";
                    break;

                case 'f':
                    $this->query.=" WHERE ".$datos->DatosConsulta[0];
                    break;
            }
            } else{

            }

            for ($i=1; $i < sizeof($datos->Val) ; $i++) { 
                if($datos->DatosConsulta[$i] != ""){
            switch ($datos->TipoDato[$i]) {
                case 's':
                    $this->query.=" AND ".$datos->CampoConsulta[$i]." LIKE CONCAT('".$datos->DatosConsulta[$i]."' , '%')";
                    break;

                case 'i':
                    $this->query.=" AND ".$datos->CampoConsulta[$i]." LIKE CONCAT(".$datos->DatosConsulta[$i]." , '%')";
                    break;
                case 'f':
                $this->query.=" AND ".$datos->DatosConsulta[$i];
                break;

            }
            } 
            }

        }else{
            if($datos->DatosConsulta[0] != ""){
            switch ($datos->TipoDato[0]) {
                case 's':
                    $this->query.=" WHERE ".$datos->CampoConsulta[0]." LIKE CONCAT('".$datos->DatosConsulta[0]."' , '%')";
                    break;

                case 'i':
                    $this->query.=" WHERE ".$datos->CampoConsulta[0]." LIKE CONCAT(".$datos->DatosConsulta[0]." , '%')";
                    break;
                case 'f':
                    $this->query.=" WHERE ".$datos->DatosConsulta[0];
                    break;
            }
            }  
        }
           $this->query.=" group by direcciones.nombre, departamentos.nombre_depto;";
//               echo $this->query;
        $resultado = $this->conexion_bd->query($this->query);
        //Variable que construira la tabla
        $tblHtml = ' <thead class="thead-dark text-center">
                                    <tr class="text-center align-items-center">
                                        <th scope="col">#</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Clave Dirección</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Dirección</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Clave Depto</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Depatamento</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Total</th>
                                        <th scope="col">Fecha</th>

                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>';
        //contador de items
        $items = 1;
//Se compara si existe al menos un resultado de la consulta
        $row_cnt = $resultado->num_rows;
        if ($row_cnt >= 1) {
            //Se obtienen los resultados de la consulta
            while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {

                $tblHtml.=' <tr class="text-center">
                                    <td>'.$items.'</td>
                                    <td>'.$fila[0].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$fila[1].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$fila[2].'</td> 
                                    <td>'.$fila[4].'</td>
                                    <td>'.$fila[5].'</td>
                                </tr>';
                $items++;
            }
            $tblHtml.='</tbody>';
            echo $tblHtml;
        } else {
            echo "No hay registros";
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {

    }
}
```

Lo que busco es agrupar todas las departamentos de una Dirección.

Answer (score 0):

intentando un poco mi solución fue crear una variable auxiliar donde debía almacenar el nombre de la dirección y compararla en un `if` dentro del `while` que obtiene las filas de la consulta.

```
//contador de items
    $items = 1;
    $aux="";
//Se compara si existe al menos un resultado de la consulta
    $row_cnt = $resultado->num_rows;
    if ($row_cnt >= 1) {
        //Se obtienen los resultados de la consulta
        while ($fila = $resultado->fetch_row()) {
          if($fila[3] === $aux){
         $tblHtml.=' <tr class="text-center">
                                <td>'.$items.'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[0].'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[1].'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[2].'</td> 
                                <td>'.$fila[4].'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[5].'</td>
                            </tr>';
   }else{
   $tblHtml.='<th>'.$fila[3].'</th>';
   $tblHtml.=' <tr class="text-center">
                                <td>'.$items.'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[0].'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[1].'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[2].'</td> 
                                <td>'.$fila[4].'</td>
                                <td>'.$fila[5].'</td>
                            </tr>';
   }

            $items++;
            $aux=$fila[3];
        }
        $tblHtml.='</tbody>';
        echo $tblHtml;
```